# Use PHP Session within socket.io

Tags: php, node.js, session, websocket, haproxy

the last two days I read thousands of Google/Stackoverflow-Posts regarding how to share a PHP session with socket.io-websocket using redis. In fact: No solution works for me. Basically: Websockets run perfectly. My setup so far:

Webbrowser(Client)HTTPS -> HAProxy(443) -> Apache(81) | redis | node.js(8443)

Ok. How can I use the Session-Data generated in PHP in the node.js websocket-server to identify which user communicated with the socket?

PHP stores all Session-Data in redis. But with node I can't access this data. Empty. No cookie etc. But when I trigger http://host:nodejsport node.js writes his own session-data into redis.

I deleted all my code.

Or is it much better to send a token (phpsessid or jwt or own token) with each websocket request and read at node-js-side from redis the token<->user-association?

Please help me. I can't no more ..... ;) Can't figure out the problem. It's like I have two parallel sessions. But cookie-name and php-session-name (in redis) are well configures in php and nodejs.

thanks in advance!

Comment: PHP sessions can only be used within PHP. Well, that's basically the deal. I'm not familiar how you use php sessions with redis. Any code?

Comment: Are you sure? Read many times that it is possible to Share Sessions via redis between php and node.js

Comment: What is your use case? It's not quite typical to want to share a session between separate incompatible web servers. Usually, one server manages the user session and then makes calls to other services on the user's behalf.

Comment: I installed the php_redis extension and configured redis as session handler. Then used session-functions as always.

Comment: My case is the following: my php-app logs users in. For realtime-notifications I use websockets via socket.io. So on the node.hs side I habe to identify the user to load the user-data (let's say a chat example in which I have to load the username or load saves channels the users wants to subscribe to lile his own groups/chatrooms). All this is done at the node-side. Therefore iI want to pass the session id that i can load the user data througj the user id which is stored in the session.

Comment: Any further ideas or design concepts? Can't figure it out. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike. Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Hey. No. I switched over to the following stack (which is working perfectly and ssl encrypted): crossbar.io, autobahn, nginx as reverseproxy with ssl termination, redis to share session data and apache as webserver. From php side i use predis and thruway.